# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$

I think
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$
Therefore
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cosh x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx.$$

But I think this rearrangement is meaningless.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The rearrangement is correct, However I don't think you will get this in terms of "nice" function, your best bet is something like the exponential integral